# How to add a custom font (.TTF) in BB cascades?

Tags: qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am developing an **app** in which I need to have a label with my custom fonts.
I can't find a solution to load a `.ttf` file into qml. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Pressently with the cascades/Qt framework it is not supported,It will be supported in future releases.
Plz refer cascades roadmaps
https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/roadmap/

Answer (score 0):

It could be tricky getting it into QML, the recommended way for using fonts is: [QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont) but I'm unsure if that'll work on Blackberry as it does have issues on various platforms.

Answer (score 0):

both solutions are wrong the proper one what i use is to create a weview and add fonts in the webview and then you can have the 2 way communication between the webview and the qml.
Please take a look at the funkypigeon app when you crete inside text of the card.